# How to create index on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

When traverse vertex or egde, It is very slow.

I want to create index for accelerating speed.

```
# match (n:v{id:1}) return n;
        n        
-----------------
 v[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)

Time: 693.100 ms
```

How can I create index for vertex or edge?

Answer (score 1):

Use "CREATE PROPERTY INDEX" statement for create index on graph object.

```
# match (n:v{id:1}) return n;
        n        
-----------------
 v[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)

Time: 693.100 ms
# create property index on v ( id );
CREATE PROPERTY INDEX
Time: 2227.147 ms
# match (n:v{id:1}) return n;
        n        
-----------------
 v[3.1]{"id": 1}
(1 row)

Time: 5.935 ms
```

In this case, accelerated over than hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

- Creating Index

  `agens=> CREATE PROPERTY INDEX ON [VERTEX OR EDGE LABEL] ([PROPERTY])
   agens=> CREATE PROPERTY INDEX ON CUSTOMER (AGE)`
- Creating Unique Index (Allow only one edge between two vertices)

  `agens=> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [INDEX NAME] ON [GRAPH_PATH.VERTEX OR EDGE LABEL] ([PROPERTIES])
   agens=> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX STUDENT_UNIQ_INDEX ON [AGENS_GRAPH.CUSTOMER] ("start", "end")`
- Creating Unique Constraint

  `agens=> CREATE CONSTRAINT ON [VERTEX OR EDGE LABEL] [PROPERTY] IS UNIQUE
   agens=> CREATE CONSTRAINT ON CUSTOMER CUSTOMER_ID IS UNIQUE`